# Resuming in enumerate with roman numerals

Tags: enumerate, roman-numerals

I want to suspend and resume an enumerated list, with Roman numerals. I am using the enumerate and mdwlist packages and have the following:

```
\begin{enumerate}[I]
\item Item
\item Item
\suspend{enumerate}
Text in between...
\resume{enumerate}
\item Item
\item Item
\end{enumerate}
```

But the way it comes out is that the first two items (before suspending) are numbered I and II (as desired), and the second two items (after resuming) are numbered 3 and 4. How do I get those to be numbered III and IV?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As the documentation of `mdwlist` shows, you need to repeat the optional argument to `enumerate` in this situation; it needs a couple of extra level of brackets:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumerate,mdwlist}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[I]
\item Item
\item Item
\suspend{enumerate}
Text in between...
\resume{enumerate}[{[I]}]
\item Item
\item Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively you can used the `enumitem` package with the `shortlabels` option to get the same syntax for specifying labels in `enumerate` and use its `resume*` option for the resumed list.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[I]
\item Item
\item Item
\end{enumerate}
Text in between...
\begin{enumerate}[resume*]
\item Item
\item Item
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, I see. Couldn't find that in the documentation! Thanks.

Comment: Its page 5, just before the Implementation section.